# Can I use IIS as the development server with "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, npm

I have created a React app and can "npm start" to use its built-in development server on port 3000 successfully, but I'd like to be able to run and debug my app in the context of my local IIS web server (so that I can refer to other services on that site using my current integrated authentication credentials).

Is there a way to tell "npm start" to not use its own built-in dev server and to use IIS instead (with the hot reloading whenever I change something in React)?

I can run it in IIS fine, so long as I "npm run-script build" first, then reload my browser, but that's just a wee bit undesirable during development.

Thanks.

PS, I used this to create the app: "npx create-react-app my-app --typescript"

Comment: Until I can find a way for IIS to serve it and do hot module replacement, I've changed my API service (on port 80) to use identity impersonation and enabled anonymous access (with CORS turned on) so that my React app on port 3000 can use the API as well as my identity. Once it gets built and published to a separate web server, I've edited my config transform files to remove the identity impersonation and CORS settings from web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full description of how I changed my web service in IIS to enable CORS and identity impersonation, so that my localhost:3000 React app could use it without fuss:

http://marcfearby.com/blog/computing/developing-in-react-with-an-api-hosted-in-iis

Comment: I commented on your blog the other day but it looks like it was taken down. There are many questions and possible flaws with your approach.  If you can still access the comment, please review and let me know if you can answer my questions.

Comment: My blog must have thought it was spam since it contained URLs and blocked it. I've now approved it. To answer your question, you don't want to call your API on port 3000 because it doesn't run on port 3000 (the "npm start" web server), it should be running on port 80 (I presume). Also, try getting it to work first without encrypting the identity impersonation bit (that's too much effort until you can get it to work plainly)

Comment: Also, I didn't set baseUrl in my React app because I didn't want to mess with its own routings. All I'm doing is just calling localhost/api directly in my Axios requests within the app, no port 3000 anywhere in my Axios calls. And thanks for pointing out my type. It's now fixed :-)

Comment: Ok, so you are using IIS Express.  That's not clear in this question/answer/blog.  I was really hoping this was for Local IIS because I have an internal API that requires Windows auth and is hosted on Local IIS.  It seems I'm the first in the world to try to do this because the only posts I've found online deal with IIS Express.

Comment: I'm using IIS 10.0.15063.0, the one you get when you "Turn Windows features on or off". I've never used IIS Express before and always tell Visual Studio to use Local IIS (Project > Properties > Web).

Comment: I'm very confused by what you're doing.  If you're using localhost that is IIS Express.  Anyway, I was able to use your method by converting my API to use IIS Express and debugging it alongside my web app.  So despite the confusion, I got it working thanks to you.  I would like to understand more how you're getting a localhost URL while using Local IIS, though.

Answer (score 0):

Any server will work which can serve static js files. Make sure you do required configuration to load index.html on every request.

As react app will be bootstrapped using index.html, so this should be the file which will be loaded all the time.

Comment: I can already do this, but it's the hot reloading in IIS that has me scratching my head